# What does the "c" in cmake stand for?

Tags: cmake

I've not been able to find a definitive answer on google. I think it means cross-platform.

Is there another site that is more appropriate for this kind of question?

Comment: I also would have guessed that it stands for *cross-platform*. In their own words, *CMake is an open-source, cross-platform family of tools designed to build, test and package software*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It stands for **cross-platform** . 
See the [Statement from Brad King](https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14012#c32631)

It does not stand for `compile` or `cross compile` but generates the make/project files for this step.

It does not stand for `C` or `C++` because multiple programming languages are supported.

It does not stand for the third generation of any of the `make` / `nmake` tools because they are still required.